# Trying To Create a Slidebar Menu in IOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, swrevealviewcontroller

I want to create a slidebar menu in my app (As shown in the image below)
[image]

When I click that hamburger icon, it should show a menu as shown below. 
[image]

I am currently using the SWRevealController, a lib written in Objective C. I created a bridging header and imported the class. This is my current Set up
[image]

My initial view which branches to a Menu Controller or the UIViewTable is a SWRevealController, and the segues are subclasses of SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController. In my Food Item View Controller (the controller where the hamburger navigation exist), I added the following code to activate the slidebar action.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Creating the slidebar Navigation using SWRevealViewController 
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

}
```

However, when I click the button, it is still not responding. When I did this with my other application, it worked fine. I am not sure why it is not working here

This is the source I used as reference: http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

View Controller Full Code

```
@IBOutlet weak var thumbnail_image: UIImageView!
    //@IBOutlet weak var food_detail: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testing: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    var jsonResponseFood: NSArray = NSArray() //API for types of food available
    var jsonResponseRecipe: NSArray = NSArray() // API for recipes in food
    var selectedFood: foodItem?
    var postStr: String?

    //Initializing API
    let FullRecipeAPIModel = fullRecipeAPIModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Creating the slidebar Navigation using SWRevealViewController 
        if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }


        print(selectedFood?.name as String!)
        //testing.text = self.selectedFood?.name

        let APIModel = apiModel()

        APIModel.delegate = self
        FullRecipeAPIModel.delegate = self
        APIModel.downloadItems(postString: postStr!)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Thank you StackOverflow.

Comment: one question menu button for referenced as IBOutlet to left bar button item right ?\

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: can you attach your project

Comment: Share full code of view controller

Comment: your connection is wrong ,

Comment: @Vinodh - problem not in the code , problem in conncetion, the questiioner wrongly establish the connection in SWL,

Comment: Okay @Anbu.Karthik i thought some problem with the code

Comment: @J_LIU - r u there

Comment: Hi, yes I can post my code, sorry, where do you want me to post

Comment: @J_LIU - can u attach ur project

Comment: Not sure, how to do that

Comment: I have my code on github, https://github.com/Jenniferliu1272/smif_ios_cleaned.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your code is you are not setting SWRevealController as root view.No Storyboard option available by code wise we have to do configuration once again. This library was designed  like that. so if you change code as below it will work like a charm.

```
if(stat == "login"){
                if(responseString == "invalid"){
                    self.isValid = false;
                    print(self.isValid)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if self.checkLogin(data: responseString!) == true {
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "food", bundle: nil)
                        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foodItemViewController") as! foodItemViewController
                        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                        let menuView :MenuController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuBar") as! MenuController
                        let revealController = SWRevealViewController()

                        revealController.frontViewController = navController;
                        revealController.rearViewController = menuView;

                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = revealController

                    }
                    else{
                        //Show alert here
                        self.showAlert(title: "User Does Not Exist", alertTitle: "Close", message: "");
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                //CODE COULD BE SIMPLIFIED
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    if(responseString == "duplicate"){
                        //Show alert here
                        self.showAlert(title: "User with this email already exist", alertTitle: "Close", message: "Please register with another email address")
                    }
                    else{
                        //Show Food UITable
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "food", bundle: nil)
                        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "entranceFoodController") 
                        /*let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller) // Creating a navigation controller with VC1 at the root of the navigation stack.*/
                        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

                        let menuView :MenuController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuBar") as! MenuController
                        let revealController = SWRevealViewController()

                        revealController.frontViewController = controller;
                        revealController.rearViewController = menuView;

                        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = revealController                    }

                });
            }
```

Comment: So I made the changes as suggested, it is still not working :(

Comment: Hi Vinodh, I ran into a problem with adding the slidebar menu for my other view, can I ask you another question?

Comment: Sorry for the extremely late response. Here is my question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554848/sidebar-menu-is-not-working-when-it-is-coming-back-from-the-detail-view-controll I have updated my github code based on my new problem

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on this today, is that the best choice available to use SWRevealController, isn't there an Apple built in way of doing this?. I am eager to see options instead of getting something form Github, unless that is my last resort.

Comment: mhmm i am not sure, but I quite liked SWRevealController, it was quite straightforward. I used it before in another app, and it worked well, but don't know why its not working here

Comment: Is SWREVEALCONTROLLER the best option, I am working in SWIFT3.

Comment: I have not tried any other, but SWREVEALCONTROLLER is one of the easier ones to use, based on experience