# SideBar Menu is not working when it is coming back from the detail View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a Sidebar menu. The sidebar menu is shown in the image below. This sidebar menu works fine.

[image]

However, my problem is that when I go from the table view controller to the detail view controller (titled smif in the image), and click back, my sidebar menu no longer works. I am using SWRevealViewController to make the sidebar menu work. 
[image]

Code available upon request. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set target action for menu button as `revealToggle:` (api exposed by SWRevealViewController) in your detail view controller.

**Example: Swift3.0**

```
   if revealViewController() != nil {
                sideBarButton.target = revealViewController()
                sideBarButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Add below code in your classes:

1- In all your view controllers add             `self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer()` just after where you are setting actions as revealToggle()

2- In MenuController add below code:

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if (self.revealViewController()) != nil{
            self.revealViewController().frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        }


    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let revealVC = self.revealViewController() {
            revealVC.frontViewController.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

    }
```

Comment: I got you. Your issue is when you are tapping on the detail view controller the rear view doesn't closed right. See my updated answer

Comment: Well, not exactly, my problem is that when i go to the detailViewController, and tap back, my sideBar menu no longer works. The code above did not work

Comment: Ok, I actually I resolved my problem thank you though

Answer (score 0):

By removing the navigation controller in the detailViewController, it was able have a sidebar in both the detailViewController and the TableViewController